# AWS Athena - Cast CloudFront log time field to timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm following the example [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html) gave for creating a CloudFront log table in Athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.cloudfront_logs (
  `date` DATE,
  time STRING,
  location STRING,
  bytes BIGINT,
  requestip STRING,
  method STRING,
  host STRING,
  uri STRING,
  status INT,
  referrer STRING,
  useragent STRING,
  querystring STRING,
  cookie STRING,
  resulttype STRING,
  requestid STRING,
  hostheader STRING,
  requestprotocol STRING,
  requestbytes BIGINT,
  timetaken FLOAT,
  xforwardedfor STRING,
  sslprotocol STRING,
  sslcipher STRING,
  responseresulttype STRING,
  httpversion STRING,
  filestatus STRING,
  encryptedfields INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://your_log_bucket/prefix/'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'skip.header.line.count'='2' )
```

Creating the table with the `time` field as a `string` doesn't allow me to run conditional queries.  I tried re-creating the table with the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.cloudfront_logs (
  `date` DATE,
  time timestamp,
....
```

Unfortunately this did not work and I received no results in the `time` field when I previewed the table.

Does anyone have any experience casting the `time` to something that I can use to query?

Comment: After some additional research I came up with the following query:

```SELECT *, date_parse(time, '%H:%i:%s') as converted_time
FROM "default"."cloudfront_logs" 
WHERE requestip = '207.30.46.111'
AND date_parse(time, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN timestamp '1970-01-01 06:00:00' AND timestamp '1970-01-01 12:00:00'
ORDER BY date desc
limit 10```

The query is not ideal since the `date_parse` function converts the time string to `1970-01-01 HH:MM:SS` format.  But its a start.

Answer (score 4):

Concat the date and time into a timestamp in a subquery:

```
WITH ds AS 
    (SELECT *,
         parse_datetime( concat( concat( format_datetime(date,
         'yyyy-MM-dd'), '-' ), time ),'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss') AS datetime
    FROM default.cloudfront_www
    WHERE requestip = '207.30.46.111')
SELECT *
FROM ds
WHERE datetime
    BETWEEN timestamp '2018-11-19 06:00:00'
        AND timestamp '2018-11-19 12:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's frustrating that there isn't a straightforward way to have usable timestamps (dates with times included) in a table based on CloudFront logs.

However, this is now my workaround:

I create a *view* based on the original table. Say my original table is `cloudfront_prod_logs`. I create a view, `cloudfront_prod_logs_w_datetime` that has a proper `datetime`/timestamp field and I use that in queries, instead of the original table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cloudfront_prod_logs_w_datetime AS 
SELECT
  "date_parse"("concat"(CAST(date AS varchar), ' ', CAST(time AS varchar)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') datetime
, *
FROM
  cloudfront_prod_logs
```